# create native query JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i got error in my codes like this :

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 42. Error Code: -1 Call: select userLevelId from USERS where id = :id Query: DataReadQuery(sql="select userLevelId from USERS where id = :id ")

and my code :

```
        public String cek() { if (tmp.equals(tmp2)) {
          y =1;
          level = getItems().toString(); } 
          .....
          .....
        }


       public List<Users> getItems() {
         if (y.equals(1)) {
         y=0;
         tmp = tmp.trim();
         return em.createNativeQuery("select userLevelId from USERS where id = :id")
         .setParameter("id", tmp).getResultList(); }
    }
```

so where's my fault ?
can anyone help me ?
thx b4

Comment: Are you missing quotes? `select userLevelId from USERS u where u.id = ':id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main Problem**

- Native queries don't use named parameter syntax (`:id`). Use prepared statement syntax with the `?`. Then use. `setParameter( indexOf?, value )` . For example

  ```
  ...("select userLevelId from USERS where id = ?")
  ...setParameter(1, tmp)
  ```

**Other Notes**

- Don't do your querying in the getter if the getter is part of the property binding. For instance if you have `List<User> items` as a bean property, don't do any business logic or in your case querying in the getter. The getter may be called for a few number of reason, apart from what you expect. Instead you can initialize it in a `@PostConstruct` method or in your constructor. If you need to update the list, have a listener method that will update it, and directly call *that* method
- A common practice is to separate the business layer and web layer (the managed bean). The business layer can be an EJB in which you inject into the managed bean

Comment: btw sorry before,, i want to debug my projectin netbeans 8.0,, why when i'm debug but the system do build my project ? what i must do ?

Comment: Are you asking why Netbeans builds your project before it starts debug mode?

Comment: no, i had already buil my project, but when i run/debug , after that netbeans do build my project again so that my project not showing. sorry if my words make you confused.. hehe